# Is possible start a iOS App on device boot?

Tags: ios

I am developing iOS App (iPhone/iPad) that needs be started when the device is turned on.

The app should be started on device boot.

Is this possible on iOS using Swift?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to start your app whenever the device boots. Depending on what you need, there may be other alternatives such as running some code in the background when the app receives a Push Notification or turning on Background Fetch, though in the latter case, the system still has control on when to launch your app.

Comment: Thanks by answer. I will verify if this solution solves my problem